# The fastest way to fill table using data from other tables

Tags: sql, t-sql, functional-programming

I've read the conception behind functional programing and that makes me reconsider my way of doing things.

For example, there is a table:

```
 - Client, Date, Trial, Full
 - Client1, 14.11.2012, 1, 1
 - Client1, 06.02.2013, NULL, 1
 - Client1, 27.03.2013, NULL, 1
 - Client1, 15.05.2013, NULL, 1
```

The table contains millions records and half a million clients. My goal is to transform this data to something like a status of client:

```
 - Client, Date, Status
 - Client1, 14.11.2012, 'Mixed'
 - Client1, 01.12.2012, 'Unprocessed'
 - Client1, 01.01.2012, 'Unprocessed'
 - Client1, 13.01.2013, 'Slept'
 - Client1, 01.02.2013, 'Slept'
 - Client1, 06.02.2013, 'Processed'
 - Client1, 01.03.2013, 'Unprocessed'
 - Client1, 27.03.2013, 'Processed'
 - Client1, 01.04.2013, 'Unprocessed'
 - Client1, 01.05.2013, 'Unprocessed'
 - Client1, 15.05.2013, 'Processed'
 - Client1, 01.06.2013, 'Unprocessed'
 - Client1, 01.07.2013, 'Unprocessed'
 - Client1, 23.07.2013, 'Slept'
 - Client1, 01.08.2013, 'Slept'
 - Client1, 01.09.2013, 'Slept'
 - Client1, 01.10.2013, 'Slept'
 - Client1, 01.11.2013, 'Slept'
 - Client1, 01.12.2013, 'Slept'
 - Client1, 01.01.2014, 'Slept'
 - Client1, 10.01.2014, 'Left'
```

The short algorithm of the transformation is:

1. If it's the first row and Trial = 1 and Full = 1 then Status = 'Mixed'
2. If there is no data for a first day of month then Status = 'Unprocessed'
3. If 60 days passed and there is no records containing Full = 1 then Status = 'Slept'
4. If 240 days passed and there is no records containing Full = 1 then Status = 'Left'
5. If there is a first day of month and previous Status = 'Slept' then
   Status = 'Slept

There are a lot of cases I skipped, because the algorithm isn't issue, but tools.

In order to transform data within SQL I used the following expressions:

- row_number() over (partition by [Client] order by [Date] asc)
- lag([Date],1) over (partition by [Client] order by [Date] desc)
- dateadd(day,1,eomonth([Date]))
- recursion
- etc

I have feeling that it can't be the fastest way to transform data, also multi-treading (put every client in separate tread) may be very helpful, not sure how good sql at that. My execution plan is really huge after big number of extra cases.

So, my question is what tool is the best to transform this data like that? Probably, programming language can handle that the way better?

**Update**: I prepared the requested SQL code. Feel free to find any issue:
http://pastebin.com/3nCdfquG

Comment: Can you post your SQL that you already have?  How well indexed is the data?  This doesn't sound like it should be too hard for SQL to accomplish efficiently.

Comment: SQL will perform any transformation and inserting just fine, as long as it is possible to understand what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: I just wonder if my approach is generally well considered. Will put the code later, maybe sql is indeed enough and my code is not well designed.

Comment: Perhaps can consider SSIS? In the Data Flow Task, you can have a Script Component where you can apply your algorithm.

Comment: @iamdave I've updated my post with my sql code: it's huge, so, I've put in pastebin.

Comment: @ajeh I've updated my post with my sql code: it's huge, so, I've put in pastebin.

Comment: @irawan-soetomo I had this idea. However I have to separate clients list into groups (treads) to support parallelism, right?

Comment: Can you put a bit more source data into your question so we have something to test against?  Your SQL solution (which isn't all that big) can definitely be improved upon,

Comment: @iamdave compressed csv to zip: goo.gl/NyuHBb

Comment: @user1464922  Are you processing this one client at a time, or do you want to output a data set that contains this journey for every client?

Comment: Dataset, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The below assumes you'll process one client at a time, for example into a Customer Report**

---

I have used the dataset you provided, uploaded into a table called `ClientData` with the following index applied which may be slightly overkill as it essentially created a duplicate of your data, but makes things lightening quick:

```
create nonclustered index ix_CientData_Client_Date
on dbo.ClientData(Client,Date)
include (Trial,[Full])
```

I have then created a dates table based on a given `Client` ID, from their first `Date` value to the lesser of their last `Date` value + 240 days or today.

From this table, you can then filter out all useless dates.  `Join` that dataset to itself to get the previous `ClientData` row and process your `Status` Logic.

As you have not included the entire set of logical processes I have completed what I can, leaving in `ERROR` messages for if you start changing things.  I find this useful in pinpointing why a `case` statement isn't quite doing what I want it to:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#ClientJourney') is not null
drop table #ClientJourney

declare @Client nvarchar(50) = '0x802B52540027E50211E24949C409C617'

declare @MinDate date = (select min(Date)
                        from ClientData
                        where Client = @Client
                        )
declare @MaxDate date = (select case when dateadd(d,240,max(Date)) > getdate()
                                    then getdate()
                                    else dateadd(d,240,max(Date))
                                    end
                        from ClientData
                        where Client = @Client
                        )

--select max(Date), @MinDate,@MaxDate, datediff(d,max(date),@MaxDate) from ClientData where Client = @Client


-- Create a table of dates between @MinDate and @MaxDate with a recursive cte
;with Dates as
(
select @MinDate as DateValue
        ,case when datepart(day,@MinDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as MonthStart

union all

select dateadd(d,1,DateValue)
        ,case when datepart(day,dateadd(d,1,DateValue)) = 1 then 1 else 0 end as MonthStart
from Dates
where DateValue < @MaxDate
)
-- Then exclude any that aren't either the first of the month, in the ClientData table or the @MaxDate value
select row_number() over (order by DateValue) as RowNum
        ,d.DateValue
        ,d.MonthStart
        ,c.Trial
        ,c.[Full]
into #ClientJourney
from Dates d
    left join ClientData c
        on(d.DateValue = c.Date
            and c.Client = @Client
            )
where d.MonthStart = 1
    or c.Date is not null
    or d.DateValue = @MaxDate
option (maxrecursion 0)


-- Pull that data out, joining to itself to get the previous item of ClientData and then process the Status
select j.RowNum
        ,j.DateValue
        ,j.MonthStart
        ,j.Trial
        ,j.[Full]

        -- Handling of first line in dataset
        ,case when j.RowNum = 1
            then case when j.Trial is not null
                            and j.[Full] is not null
                        then 'Mixed'
                    when j.Trial is null
                            and j.[Full] is not null
                        then 'Full'
                    when j.Trial is not null
                            and j.[Full] is null
                        then 'Trial'
                    else 'ERROR1'
                    end

            -- Handling rest of dataset
            else case when j.MonthStart = 1                                                 -- First of the month
                        then case when j.Trial is not null                                      -- WITH client data
                                        or j.[Full] is not null
                                    then 'Processed'

                                when j.Trial is null                                            -- WITHOUT client data
                                        and j.[Full] is null
                                    then case when datediff(d,jp.DateValue,j.DateValue) < 60        -- For less than 60 days
                                                    then 'Unprocessed'
                                                when datediff(d,jp.DateValue,j.DateValue) < 240     -- For less than 240 days
                                                    then 'Slept'
                                                else 'Left'
                                                end
                                else 'ERROR2'
                                end
                    else                                                                    -- Rest of the Month
                        case when j.[Full] = 1                                                  -- WITH Full flag
                                    then 'Processed'

                                when j.[Full] is null                                           -- WITHOUT Full flag
                                    then case when datediff(d,jp.DateValue,j.DateValue) < 60            -- For less than 60 days
                                                    then 'Unprocessed'
                                                when datediff(d,jp.DateValue,j.DateValue) < 240         -- For less than 240 days
                                                    then 'Slept'
                                                else 'Left'
                                                end
                                else 'ERROR3'
                                end

                    end
            end as Status
        ,jp.DateValue
        ,datediff(d,jp.DateValue,j.DateValue) as LastFull
from #ClientJourney j
    outer apply (select top 1 DateValue             -- This returns only the most recent ClientData row that occured before the one being selected
                    from #ClientJourney j2
                    where j.RowNum > j2.RowNum
                        and j2.[Full] is not null
                    order by DateValue desc
                ) jp


-- Clean up
if object_id('tempdb..#ClientJourney') is not null
drop table #ClientJourney
```

Comment: Thanks. I've got your idea.